# How to find element <label for="terms"> Python, selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm trying to click this button on this website. To get to it you start on https://fantasy5.com/football and once on the website you click on the login/signup button top right. then you are on the correct link and the button I am trying to press is the terms and privacy button in the signup section.

[image: HTML SOURCE]

Any advice on what code I should use to find it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to select that checkbox, use this xpath - `//div[contains(@class,'Checkbox')][1]`. Below line worked for me.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class,'Checkbox')][1]").click()
```

Answer (score 1):

we have unique id `terms`

did you try :

```
driver.find_element_by_id("terms").click()
```